# Strange compilation error in c when using an enum

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Hello in my header file Data.h i define a boolean type as an enumeration, but got a compile error and i don't understand why :

```
// Data.h
// Author : Alexandre rousset

typedef enum {NO, YES} bool;

typedef struct stud {
    char    *date;          
    char    *name;  /* student name */  
} Student;

void studentInit(Student *new);
bool studentPassExam(Student *s);
```

I got this error :

```
include/Data.h:4: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
include/Data.h:4: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: probably you compiler thinks bool is built in type.

Comment: Probably compiling as c++ instead of c.

Comment: @rabusmar do not think so, as it would complain about *new*, or?

Comment: @RomanB. well, `bool` is before `new`.

Comment: @rabusmar g++ complains about both.

Answer (score 4):

Your code compiles fine with `gcc version 4.6.2`.

Probably for your compiler `bool` is a built-in type. However, according to Standards (C89, C99) it is not. Look for options in your compiler which enforce standard compliant behavior.

(Just in case, make sure you use C and not C++ compiler. However if you have used C++ compiler, than it should have complained about `new` too. Since `new` is a keyword in C++.)